# Tween animation not working for Android

Tags: android, eclipse, animation, tween

I'm trying to do something very basic. I'm just trying to run an simple tween animation from a xml resource file for an Android application when a button is clicked. The animation will not start when I run the app. I'm going nuts trying to figure out why.

Here's the res/anim/spin.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http:schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">

    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:repeatCount="infinite"
        android:toDegrees="360" />

</set>
```

Here's my activity class:

```
    package jorge.jorge.jorge;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.view.animation.Animation;
    import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.ImageView;

    public class Assignment5Activity extends Activity {
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */

        @Override

        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);



            final Button btnSpin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
            btnSpin.setText("Start");
            btnSpin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) 
                {


                    ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                    Animation an =    AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(Assignment5Activity.this, R.anim.spin);

                    iv.startAnimation(an);

                    if (an.hasStarted())
                    {
                        btnSpin.setText("Stop");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        iv.startAnimation(an);
                    }
                }
            } ); 

        }

    }
```

Comment: Is there anything else we should know? Is this the complete code for this class?

Comment: Yeah. All I'm using is this activity class, the spin xml resource file and my main layout file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
final ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                    Animation an =        AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(Assignment5Activity.this, R.anim.spin);

 btnSpin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) 
                {




                    iv.startAnimation(an);

                    if (an.hasStarted())
                    {
                        btnSpin.setText("Stop");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        iv.startAnimation(an);
                    }
                }
            } );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a **RotateAnimation**, setting the pivot point to the centre of your image.

```
RotateAnimation anim = new RotateAnimation(0f, 350f, 15f, 15f);
anim.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
anim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
anim.setDuration(700);

// Start animating the image
final ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
iv.startAnimation(anim);

// Later.. stop the animation
iv.setAnimation(null);
```

Comment: That didn't work either. I'm not sure why. Are you suppose to define the animation resource in the manifest xml file?

Comment: @rocklandcitizen with this code you don't need to declare animation in xml!! if you want to work with animation in xml put it in your res/anim folder

Comment: The original code in my first post used the xml animation resource and it was located in the res/anim directory. I tried the code above without requesting the xml resource (just doing it programmatically as presented). For some reason that's beyond me it didn't work either. I'm thinking maybe I need to load the bitmap resource programmatically instead of loading it in my main.xml layout file. Althought that shouldn't matter in theory. I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

*spin.xml* stays the same as your xml.
Run thiscode in your button's `OnClickListener`.

```
ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
Animation an = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(Assignment5Activity.this, R.anim.spin);
iv.startAnimation(an);
```

Answer (score 0):

Give the animation a duration. I believe by default it's 0 (as opposed to property animations which are ~300msec by default).

Additionally, you can use NineOldAndroids to backport the much superior ViewPropertyAnimator approach to pre-Honeycomb.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing android:toDegrees from 360 to 359? To android, degree 0 is the same as 360 because number sequences begin at 0 not 1. So essentially, with the current setting at 360, telling it to go from degree 0 to degree 360 is like telling it to stay put.

```
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:repeatCount="infinite"
        android:toDegrees="359" />
```